# Printing the position of character in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

i have a method that prints the index of given character in a given String. If String doesn't contain given character the result is -1.
My code looks like this:

```
public static int strpos(String text, char z) {

    int x = 0;

    char[] array = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == z) {
            x = i;
            break;
        } else {
            x = -1;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(strpos("abcdefghc", 'c'));
}
```

In this situation the result is *2*, and if i delete *break*, the result is *8*. How can i modyfi my code to get a result of both 2 and 8?

Comment: Have you tried using the `String.indexOf(char)` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the result of both with a single return.
You can, however, return an `ArrayList<Integer>`.
You'll need to:

- Initialize the list at the head of the function.
- Each time you find a number, instead of breaking, `add` it your list.
- When you finish the search, return the list.

That's how you can return multiple values easily.

Also, why is the else there?

Comment: To print -1 if given char is not in the string.

Comment: @PiotrWanjas Test the method with 'c' and the string "abcdefgch", without the `break`. You should get a 7, but you'll get a -1 because of that `else`.The -1 should definitely appear, but not there.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store the indices in a `List<Integer>` and change the method to return it:

```
public static List<Integer> strpos(String text, char z) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

    char[] array = text.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != z) {
            continue;
        }

        list.add(i);
    }

    return indices.isEmpty() ? Arrays.asList(-1) : indices;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just add it to the list if it _is_ equal?

Comment: @Neo I'm confused, as that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Logically yes, but you implement it by `continue` if the char is different than `z`. Isn't it easier to just check if it is equal to `z` and add it if yes? No `continue` needed, less lines, and more readable.

Comment: @Neo It's personal preference, as I tend to deal with numerous conditions where a specific iteration of a loop should be skipped.  Ultimately, it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I agree it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type to `List<Integer>` and collect all the matching indexes in a list (or another collection of your choice).
And in that case, instead of using -1 as a special value to indicate that a character doesn't exist in the string, return empty list instead,
naturally.

Here's one way to implement that:

```
List<Integer> strpos(String text, char z) {
    return IntStream.range(0, text.length())
            .filter(i -> text.charAt(i) == z)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Alternatively, without Java 8 streams, but benefitting from `.indexOf`:

```
List<Integer> strpos(String text, char z) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = -1;
    while (true) {
        index = text.indexOf(z, index + 1);
        if (index == -1) {
            break;
        }
        indexes.add(index);
    }
    return indexes;
}
```